# How do I PInvoke RpcMgmtEpEltInqNext?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, rpc

The search term `RpcMgmtEpEltInqNext` on both Stackoverflow and PInvoke.net yields zero results, so this should be worth asking. I've been fiddling around on MSDN and looking through Win SDK *.h files all day, and feeling a bit out of my element.

I'm basically attempting to query the MSRPC endpoint mapper with managed code. Here is what I have so far:

```
[DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RpcBindingFromStringBinding(string StringBinding, out IntPtr Binding);

[DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll")]
public static extern int RpcBindingFree(ref IntPtr Binding);

[DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RpcMgmtEpEltInqBegin(IntPtr EpBinding,
                                                int InquiryType, // 0x00000000 = RPC_C_EP_ALL_ELTS
                                                int IfId,
                                                int VersOption,
                                                string ObjectUuid,
                                                out IntPtr InquiryContext);

[DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RpcMgmtEpEltInqNext(ref IntPtr InquiryContext,
                                                out int IfId,
                                                out IntPtr Binding,
                                                out string ObjectUuid,
                                                out string Annotation);

public static List<int> QueryEPM(string host)
{
    List<int> ports = new List<int>();
    int retCode = 0; // RPC_S_OK                
    IntPtr bindingHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr inquiryContext = IntPtr.Zero;                
    IntPtr elementBindingHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    int elementIfId = 0;
    string elementUuid = string.Empty;
    string elementAnnotation = string.Empty;

    try
    {                    
        retCode = RpcBindingFromStringBinding("ncacn_ip_tcp:" + host, out bindingHandle);
        if (retCode != 0)
            throw new Exception("RpcBindingFromStringBinding: " + retCode);

        retCode = RpcMgmtEpEltInqBegin(bindingHandle, 0, 0, 0, string.Empty, out inquiryContext);
        if (retCode != 0)
            throw new Exception("RpcMgmtEpEltInqBegin: " + retCode);


        retCode = RpcMgmtEpEltInqNext (ref inquiryContext, out elementIfId, out elementBindingHandle, out elementUuid, out elementAnnotation);
        if (retCode != 0)
            throw new Exception("RpcMgmtEpEltInqNext: " + retCode);
}
```

The above code isn't complete, but it illustrates my point. The code consistently returns:

> RpcMgmtEpEltIngNext: 87

87 meaning Parameter is Incorrect according to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So I'm basically stumped at this point, and I'm sure it's because of my extremely crappy PInvoke code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p/invoke declaration is wrong. It needs to be:

```
[DllImport("Rpcrt4.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RpcMgmtEpEltInqNext(
    IntPtr InquiryContext,
    out RPC_IF_ID IfId,
    out IntPtr Binding,
    out Guid ObjectUuid,
    out IntPtr Annotation
);
```

The first parameter must be passed by value.

You'll need to translate the `RPC_IF_ID` struct. It's quite a simple one.

```
public struct RPC_IF_ID
{
    public Guid Uuid;
    public ushort VersMajor;
    public ushort VersMinor;
}
```

The two string parameters you used were just wrong. They lead to the marshaller calling `CoTaskMemFree` on the returned value for `Annotation`. You don't want that. You will need to use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to read the value.

Don't forget to call `RpcBindingFree` and `RpcStringFree` as per the docs.

Comment: This gets me to exactly where I want to go.  Thank you.